# Can we use Poisson point process to geographically classify to determine an area borders?

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, statistics, computational-geometry

Suppose we have scattered points as in the figure, If the points' locations are known(their overlapped area they are located in is also known), can we use Poisson process to identify the borders of the overlapped areas in the figure? The points keep increasing randomly.

[image: figure shows scattered point on 2D plane]

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you could do given a set of samples is to make a Voronoi diagram and classify the area in each Voronoi cell by its central point.  Note that this *could* fail to connect different parts of an oddly shaped region if you're unlucky.

The use of a Poisson process for generating points is not really optimal for this application.  If you have a choice, you might want to use something like a Poisson Disk distribution, which is still random but covers more evenly: https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/

It makes Voronoi diagrams that look like this:  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6224396

Some of the efficient algorithms for Poisson Disk sampling actually work on the Voronoi diagram, which may be convenient.

Comment: My idea is to make use of those points yo envelope the area in question,so in the future it will be easy to judge if a point inside or outside that area(s).

Comment: If I don't want to generate points( the points are randomly increasing due to some events, you can consider each point as an event), then can these points be used to identify those areas.